Electric field near a surface
How to calculate a point's electric field near a conductor's surface?
My textbook says, firstly draw a tiny gaussian surface in the form of a cylinder, and one base inside the conductor the other one outside.
So by Gauss's law: $\dfrac{(\sigma \cdot \Delta s)}{\varepsilon_0}=\Delta s \, E$
($\sigma$ as charge density, $\Delta s$ as tiny base's area, $\varepsilon_0$ as vacuum permittivity, $E$ as electric field magnitude)
So we have: $\dfrac{\sigma}{\varepsilon_0}=E$
But why can we use $\Delta s$? It's a tiny surface but not a point, and we use a surface to calculate a point's field?
And why do we suppose electric field on base is uniform but not a function depends on position?

If you are looking at a point close enough to a conductor, you can approximate the surface as an infinite sheet, and the field from this infinite sheet is uniform.

And why do we suppose electric field on base is uniform but not a function depends on position?

Why did people used to think the Earth was flat?
